# could someone explain what is the meaning of (number % 10); , (number % 100)/10; and so-on?

Tags: javascript

my questions are involve java script , is like user enters a number such like '12345' and the result will display '1  2  3  4  5'. I found solution on google but I don't understand this :

```
digit5 = number % 10;         
digit4 = (number % 100)/10;         
digit3 = (number % 1000)/100;         
digit2 = (number % 10000)/1000;         
digit1 = number / 10000;
```

could someone explain what is the meaning of {(number % 10); , (number % 100)/10; and so-on?

Comment: % modulo and / is normal division

Comment: but how does it affects the result that can make 12345 to 1  2  3  4  5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The % sign is the Quotient.

So in your example:
The number is = 12345

so `number % 1000;`

is basically 12345 divide to 1000 which is 12 and 345/1000,

Now the % action will result with the remains Quotient which is 345,

Later you divided it by 100 which result with 3.45,

When you will use something li Math.floor() you will end with number 3

Answer (score 0):

`%` Arithmetic Operators

- [What does the percent sign mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934173/what-does-the-percent-sign-mean-in-php)
- [What is the PHP operator % and how do I use it in real-world examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204919)

> Take a look at [the arithmetic operators](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

**Example - Name - Result**

$a / $b - Division - Quotient of $a and $b.

$a % $b - Modulo - Remainder of $a divided by $b.